# Is it acceptable to ask a question which asks for people to help test code?

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to ask a question which asks for people to help test code?

In my case the code is a WordPress plugin which although compatible with WordPress 3.8.2, it does not seem to work with 3.8.3. I'd like to hear if anyone else experiences the same problems I've come across but am not sure if Stack Overflow is the right place for this sort of request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most probable answer to "Has anyone else experienced the same problem?" is "Yes."  This question has the same problems as dropping into a chat room and asking for permission to ask a question.  Most chat rooms will tell you "don't ask if you can ask, just ask."

What remains is the usual process we ask from all folks having code problems: post a brief snippet of code that reproduces the problem, and describe the problem in detail, including an exact copy/paste of the relevant portion of the error message you are getting.

Comment: The first question isn't right, I'm not asking for people to do that. I don't expect people to go to those lengths. The plugin in question isn't my own work, it's a popular plugin made by the guys at 10up. So leading nicely on to the second question "is anyone else experiencing the same problem" - that sounds spot on and is exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly.